# Can't click inside login form

Tags: css, forms, authentication

I have a login form in the top of one of my sites that just started being unresponsive. You can try to click inside to write something and you just can't.

The site is: https://www.sbceoportal.org/

Any tips on how to get this to work again?

Comment: that website is offline...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code to mycustomlogin class

```
.mycustomlogin {display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;}
```

Comment: hmm, this fixes the issue of not being able to login, but there is a button that appears if it detects you are coming from a certain IP. I want this button on the far left, but it is next to the login form now. This is a screenshot of how the button looks now: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5O1VbzcftyGM01VazNLZFE5QTg/view?usp=sharing  But this is how I want it to look: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5O1VbzcftyGcnp1SF9GNGt6Z00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly! Thank you so much! Can you explain to me why this works and why it needed to be done? It looks like updating my theme is what broke this, but I don't quite understand why this fixes it. Thanks a million!

Comment: Your site uses float approach which has these overflow issues. I think its better to use flex instead. That is what I did. And property space-between pushes elements to the sides of the parent element. 
Happy to help. I would appreciate if you mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I appreciate it. I marked your answer as correct.